# After viewholder swiped view doesn't restore layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, swipe

I am making a view holder swipe for like. but when I am swipe view its get 2 view holder swiped.

````
                llBillView = viewHolder?.itemView?.findViewById(R.id.llBillBG)!!
                val clAdd = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.ll)
                clAdd.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                if (!isSwiped) {
                    val translationX = Math.min(-dX, (llBillView.width / 4).toFloat())
                    llBillView.translationX = -translationX
                    // Logger.i("child draw inside $dX")
                }
                isSwiped = false

            }```

I want to swipe only 1 view holder at a time. thanks in advance.
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Anuj. I'd suggest adding a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that your issue can be found and fixed quickly by others on SO. Also, adding screenshots can be helpful to the question.

Answer (score 0):

remove it from your list that adapter is using and also notify adapter with `notifyItemRemoved(position);`

Comment: thanks for replay. but this solution is not worked.